# onLocationChanged doesn't work?

Tags: java, android

on LocationChanged listener don't work.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimpleLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
            int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Lat:" + lat + " Lng:" + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Value",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1,
                (LocationListener) this);
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "onLocationChanged Lat:" + lat + " Lng:" + lng,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't get a Toast at all? Try putting requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this); instead.

Comment: where to write requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);

Comment: Do you get any Toast at all while running this app?

Comment: yes, only one toast which is inside onCreate method.

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Lat:" + lat + " Lng:" + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: @BhargavPanchal I suspect that you have all your providers disabled, and you only get the first Toast because the provider returned by `getBestProvider(...)` has a location fix from some time ago, which is returned in `getLastKnownLocation(...)`. Try also printing the time of that location using `location.getTime()` to see if it is old.

Answer (score 0):

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1,
            (LocationListener) this);
```

which is of the format:

```
requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
```

This line in your code specifies that the location changes will be registered in your application only when there is minimum of "1" distance movement. Set that to 0 and try running your code again. Or set both minTime and minDistance to 0 and try.

Comment: check if ur "location" is returning null?